# Select Dash file Bitrates Manually in react-player

Tags: reactjs, resolution, react-player, mpd, vod

I'm using [React-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) in the project and my task is streaming MPD (DASH) files with resolution switcher feature.

based on [DASHjs](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) document first I used `getBitrateInfoListFor("video")` to get all available bitrates and then I disabled auto bitrate swithcer by this code:

```
ref.current.player
      .getInternalPlayer("dash")
      .updateSettings({
        streaming: { abr: 
        { autoSwitchBitrate: 
          { video: false } 
        } }
      });
```

and for the final step I set new quality with `setQualityFor`:

```
ref.current.player.getInternalPlayer("dash").setQualityFor("video", qualityIndex);
```

but it **doesn't work**!

the whole of the code:

```
let ref = React.createRef();
  const [VidQuality, setVidQuality] = React.useState(null);

  const getDashData= dash => {
    console.log(dash);
    setVidQuality(dash);
  };
  const updateQuality = e => {
    VidQuality?.getBitrateInfoListFor("video")?.forEach(
      quality => {
        if (quality.height === +e.target.innerHTML) {
          ref.current.player.getInternalPlayer("dash").updateSettings({
            streaming: { abr: { autoSwitchBitrate: { video: false } } }
          });
          ref.current.player
            .getInternalPlayer("dash")
            .setQualityFor("video", quality.qualityIndex);
        }
      }
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={ref}
        url="VIDEO_URL.mpd"
        controls
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        onReady={() => {
          getDashData(ref?.current?.player?.player?.dash);
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <h2>video qualities</h2>
        {VidQuality?.getBitrateInfoListFor("video")?.map(qualities => (
          <button classes="primary radius" onClick={updateQuality}>
            {qualities.height}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

and here is **[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qrqczj)**

Comment: What does "it doesn't work!" actualy mean? I suspect that you don't see a switch because the player has already buffered all of your very short video.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward
"it doesn't work" means that after clicking on a level(quality) it won't change the quality, Ok I will change URL with the longer video on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qrqczj) and i will send the results below this comment